# Fahrenheit and Celsius Bidirectional Conversion in AngularJS

Tags: data-binding, angularjs

In AngularJS, it is straightforward how to $watch a $scope variable and use that to update another. But what is the best practice if two scope variables need to watch each other?

I have as an example a bidirectional converter that will convert Fahrenheit to Celsius, and vice versa. It works okay if you type "1" into the Fahrenheit, but try "1.1" and Angular will bounce around a little before overwriting Fahrenheit that you just entered to be a slightly different value (1.1000000000000014):

```
function TemperatureConverterCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.$watch('fahrenheit', function(value) {
    $scope.celsius = (value - 32) * 5.0/9.0;
  });
  $scope.$watch('celsius', function(value) {
    $scope.fahrenheit = value * 9.0 / 5.0 + 32;
  });
}
```

Here's a plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/1fULXjx7MyAHjvjHfV1j?p=preview

What are the different possible ways to stop Angular from "bouncing" around and force it to use the value you typed as-is, e.g. by using formatters or parsers (or any other trick)?

Comment: The reason this is a good question is because this situation has infinite loop all over it - if the calculations were not inverses of each other... +1. And I'll be surprised to see any other differing answers.

Comment: Due to a background in DSP, it's hard for me to resist going into the mathematics of this, so I'll just give it up: It is possible for this to go into an infinite loop (except that Angular has a built-in limit of max iterations). Here is a great explanation of why the values "bounce" at all (due to dirty-checking): http://stackoverflow.com/a/9693933/885163. And when coupled with the limited precision of floating point, it is possible for the values to oscillate 0, 1, or more times, even indefinitely, an effect known as a "limit cycle" in IIR DSP filters. *phew* how's that for a comment?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the simplest, fastest, and most correct solution is to have a flag to track which field is being edited, and only allow updates from that field.

All you need is to use the `ng-change` directive to set the flag on the field being edited.

[Working Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/0n0golhEzU7dokMOkHN6?p=preview)

Code changes necessary:

Modify the controller to look like this:

```js
function TemperatureConverterCtrl($scope) {
  // Keep track of who was last edited
  $scope.edited = null;
  $scope.markEdited = function(which) {
    $scope.edited = which;
  };

  // Only edit if the correct field is being modified
  $scope.$watch('fahrenheit', function(value) {
    if($scope.edited == 'F') {
      $scope.celsius = (value - 32) * 5.0/9.0;
    }
  });
  $scope.$watch('celsius', function(value) {
    if($scope.edited == 'C') {
      $scope.fahrenheit = value * 9.0 / 5.0 + 32;
    }
  });
}
```

And then add this simple directive to the input fields (using `F` or `C` as appropriate):

```html
<input ... ng-change="markEdited('F')/>
```

Now only the field being typed in can change the other one.

If you need the ability to modify these fields *outside* an input, you could add a scope or controller function that looks something like this:

```js
$scope.setFahrenheit = function(val) {
  $scope.edited = 'F';
  $scope.fahrenheit = val;
}
```

Then the Celsius field will be updated on the next $digest cycle.

This solution has a bare minimum of extra code, eliminates any chance of multiple updates per cycle, and doesn't cause any performance issues.

Comment: If anyone thinks my unrelated note at the bottom is inappropriate, I will delete it. Just let me know. Thanks.

Comment: your answer is super. I've taken your extra note in good stride and appreciate it. I'll edit my question to take out (or reword) the extra demand.

Comment: Awesome, glad you weren't offended! :-)  Now I'll strip that bit out, myself.

Comment: That one hurt my head. Recursion... ng-change it is. +1

Comment: I just wanted to 800 before bed. DOH!

Comment: I appreciate your try @rGil :)

Answer (score 7):

This is a pretty good question and I'm answering it even though it's already accepted :)

In Angular, the $scope is the model. The model is a place to store data you might want to persist or use in other parts of the app, and as such, it should be designed with a good schema just as you would in a database for example.

Your model has two redundant fields for temperature, which isn't a good idea. Which one is the "real" temperature? There are times when you want to denormalize a model, just for access efficiency, but that's only really an option when the values are idempotent, which as you found, these aren't due to floating point precision.

If you wanted to continue using the model it would look something like this. You'd pick one or the other as the "source of truth" temperature, then have the other input as a convenience entry box with a formatter and parser. Let's say we want Fahrenheit in the model:

```
<input type="number" ng-model="temperatureF">
<input type="number" ng-model="temperatureF" fahrenheit-to-celcius>
```

And the conversion directive:

```
someModule.directive('fahrenheitToCelcius', function() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
      ngModel.$formatters.push(function(f) {
        return (value - 32) * 5.0 / 9.0;
      });
      ngModel.$parsers.push(function(c) {
        return c * 9.0 / 5.0 + 32;
      });
    }
  };
});
```

With this, you'd avoid the "bouncing around" because $parsers only run on user action, not on model changes. You'd still have long decimals but that could be remedied with rounding.

However, it sounds to me like you shouldn't be using a model for this. If all you want is "each box updates the other box", you can do exactly that and not even have a model. This assumes the input boxes start out blank and it's just a simple tool for users to convert temperatures. If that's the case, you have no model, no controller, and aren't even hardly using Angular at all. It's a purely view-based widget at that point, and it's basically just jQuery or jQLite. It's of limited usefulness though, since with no model it can't effect anything else in Angular.

To do that, you could just make a `temperatureConverter` directive that has a template with a couple of input boxes, and watches both boxes and sets their values. Something like:

```
fahrenheitBox.bind('change', function() {
  celciusBox.val((Number(fahrenheitBox.val()) - 32) * 5.0 / 9.0);
});
```

Comment: This answer makes a great point about designing a properly normalized schema for the $scope; Whether marking and guarding (@OverZealous' answer) or better schema design is best, may vary on an application-by-application basis, and both answers are terrific.