# Bind bidirectionaly two inputs for a converter in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to Angular and I'm trying (for training purposes) to write a converter.

What I'm trying to do is like the converter on Google search page result: https://www.google.com/search?q=1km+to+meter

[image: Google converter]

Basically, it's two inputs bound together and doing conversion stuff on change. When you update the `meter` input it updates the `kilometer` input and the opposite also works.

For now, I've used a filter to do the conversion (because I find it kind of cool for the job). You can find a live example here: http://jsfiddle.net/FMXhJ/1/

As you can see meter to kilometer works great, but I don't see how could I do the opposite way. So it seems like it won't be the solution to tackle the issue.

I wanted your help to know what is the best solution to do it.

Some `$watch` on a controller for both input is a good way to go?

Comment: This awesome reality about finding the answer when you post the question just happened once again..
I think this is my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17626761/1410020

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just use two models and update each other on the `ngChange` event:

http://jsfiddle.net/FMXhJ/2/

Or you can use watchers indeed:

http://jsfiddle.net/FMXhJ/3/

Now you'd better structure your data by having a generic convert method and an array of differents units being `{name: 'km', ratio: '0.001'}`so converting a value to another is just about multiplying by the proper ratio.

Comment: Thanks! As I commented below my question, I think I'm going to use the watchers option.

Comment: came here to finde some solution of a BindingConverter thats known in c# WPF. This helps.